# prevent pre tag in html from debugging html code

Tags: php, javascript, html

i want to know that is there any way to make  tag avoid from debugging the html code between it. because i am trying to show html code as code on a webpage but it just debugs. but it doesn't debug php, javascript or any other language script just the html, please help me so that i can show html code properly without debugging...i've searched a lot for a solution, but unfortunately all in vain..

like:-

`<div id="sayHello">`
`<h1>Hellow World!</h1>`
`</div>`

Comment: "Debug"? What are you using to debug it?

Comment: You want to just display the code?

Comment: yes i want html code to be displayed as it is..

Comment: @Jordan Arseno where should i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) php function

Use This

```
                echo "<pre>";
                echo htmlentities("<h>this is h1 tag</h>");//h=h1
                echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: worked but displaying as a normal text not as a code.

Comment: actually i can't because, i have a whole content saved in a .txt file which includes the html codes and simple text and the pre tag is as well in the txt file

Comment: @AndroidGuy use a `<pre>` tag before including that file

Comment: well then it'll display the whole content as code..because the txt file includes everything like simple text, image and all

Comment: i guess it is not possible in my case =( .btw thanx for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Run the string of html code through `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @AndroidGuy what does "debugs" mean?  I don't understand that.

Comment: i mean it converts into elements..for example if i've written code for form it just shows the form

Comment: sorry now i got the correct word, it parses into a whole form instead of displaying the script or code.

Comment: @AndroidGuy what do you mean that it's not displaying as code?  If you want to style it to look like code that's entirely up to you.  Just use CSS.

Comment: and how am i gonna do when the pre tag itself is not working

Comment: @AndroidGuy in what way is the pre tag not working?

Comment: so you are telling me to just display the code in <code> tag without using htmlentities?

Comment: actually i have the whole content saved in a .txt file which includes the html codes and simple text and the pre tag is as well in the txt file. so is there any way so that htmlentities() doesn't consider the <pre> or <code> tag

Comment: @AndroidGuy no; what you're asking to do now is very complicated.  You would have to parse the HTML to encode only the appropriate tags.

Comment: Sorry didn't get what are you trying to say?

Comment: @AndroidGuy: StackOverflow is not a place for lengthy discussion. No offence, but, you are the most frustrating user I have ever dealt with. Please go get a HTML primer - you'll be in a better position to ask the right questions. We're all hopeless in here trying to solve your issue because we have no idea what you want! Deleting my answer.

Comment: @JordanArseno well then you shouldn't blame me if you are not able to solve the problem.

Comment: @JordanArseno because i am too frustrated here, and i am trying to provide as much as info i can, so that you can solve it.

Comment: @AndroidGuy no, but we can blame *you* for not being able to solve your own problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML entities using [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: can you show me an example because i've tried covering html code like this: htmlentities($htmlcode); but it is not working

Comment: ya it worked but it is showing as a normal text instead of showing as a code, is there anyway that it leaves the <pre> tag as it is..